# Why bananas accumulate a radioactive isotope of potassium (K40)?

Tags: food, radiation

A quick google search reveals many pages that intend to calm consumers down and assure them that quantities of radioactive potassium in bananas (K40 isotope) is not sufficient to be concerned about, e.g. http://www.raw-food-health.net/Natural-Radiation.html. I am not worried that bananas may be harmful, but I wonder if bananas are actually enriched in K40 relative potassium in soil? Maybe bananas are not enriched, and so every potassium-rich food is equally radioactive... but if specifically bananas are particularly enriched in K40, then what is the mechanism of this process?

Comment: The reason, at least suggested for other food, is a high potassium content in general. In the last paragraph (**on wiki**), you might find that plants w/ high potassium content are also likely to have a high content in radium...perhaps K+ transporters / uptake mechanisms have a slightly higher affinity for Ra2+ as well ?